# Dynamically generate writer/reader from attribute names in Moose

Tags: perl, moose

In Moose we can put restrictions on instance attributes or add getters/setters like so:

```
has 'color' => (
  is  => 'rw',
  isa => 'Str',
  writer => '_set_color',
);
```

My question is, is there a way to do this dynamically for an array of elements? It's possible to do something like this:

```
has ['color', 'temperature', 'size'] => (
  is  => 'rw',
  isa => 'Str',
);
```

But is there a way to create for each of these items its own writer (or reader), e.g. `_set_color`, `_set_temperature`, `_set_size`? I tried to see if the following yielded any insight, but it returned an error

> bad accessor/reader/writer/predicate/clearer format, must be a HASH
>   ref

```
has ['color', 'temperature', 'size'] => (
  is  => 'rw',
  isa => 'Str',
  writer => sub {
    print Dumper(\@_);
    return;
);
```

What I am hoping to get is something like (which doesn't work):

```
has ['color', 'temperature', 'size'] => (
  is  => 'rw',
  isa => 'Str',
  writer => "_set_$_";
);
```

I need custom writers, so just going for the ones provided by Moose does not work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`has` isn't magic. It's just a subroutine call. So something like this should work (untested):

```
for (qw[colour temperature size]) {
  has $_ => (
    is     => 'rw',
    isa    => 'Str',
    writer => "_set_$_",
  );
}
```